# Internal Error I am getting this error in magento 2 payment page and unable to make payments

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, payment, log

Does anyone know how to solve this
[image]

Comment: have you checked log file 
---
just paste the error of log file

Comment: In log file it is showing permission issue what access we should give to Cache folder?

Comment: just paste that into your question